# Is it forbidden to go to see a doctor, trainer, etc., if that person commits shirk?

Tags: halal-haram, shirk

If a doctor, trainer, etc., commits shirk, like an Hindu, is it forbidden to see them?

Answer (score 2):

No it's not forbidden.  You're only going there for medical treatment and nothing religious.

Prophet Mohamed and Abu Bakr aSadiq used the help of a pagan as a guide to find their way to Medina from Mekka.

> The Prophet and Abu Bakr employed a man from the tribe of Bani Ad-Dail
>   and the tribe of Bani Abu bin Adi as a guide. He was an expert guide
>   and he broke the oath contract which he had to abide by with the tribe
>   of Al-Asi bin Wail and he was on the religion of Quraish pagans. The
>   Prophet and Abu Bakr had confidence in him and gave him their riding
>   camels and told him to bring them to the Cave of Thaur after three
>   days. So, he brought them their two riding camels after three days and
>   both of them set out accompanied by Amir bin Fuhaira and the Dili
>   guide who guided them below Mecca along the road leading to the
>   sea-shore.

[[Sahih al-Bukhari]](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/37/4)